# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

What this the error???

I get the old work code install new version libs and i see that error. But i can not understand what it means.

```
//index.js
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import configureStore, {history} from './store/configureStore'
import {routes} from './routes'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

const store = configureStore();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes}/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);

//routes.js
import React from 'react'
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './containers/App'

export const routes = (
    <div>
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </div>
);

//App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import NavLink from '../../components/NavLink'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <ul className='nav nav-pills'>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink onlyActiveOnIndex={true} to='/'>Главная</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What this the error? What wrong in my code?
Installed react-router-dom@^4.1.0:

Comment: Getting the same error. Found any answers so far?

Comment: @vahdet, yes `import App from './containers/App'/index`

Comment: try this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420#issuecomment-433541079

Answer (score 1):

Simply forcing it to be a function as the prop expects get's rid of the console error even though it's not the ideal solution.

```
<Route path='/' component={props => <App {...props} />} />
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420#issuecomment-433541079